# How to change URL in jsonp request AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, jsonp, parameters

I'm trying to get this API working https://lari.jumpstart.ge/en/api/v1/documentation/nbg_rates 
I've made a jsonp request and I loaded the data like so

```
var ngb_currencies = 'http://lari.jumpstart.ge/en/api/v1/nbg_currencies?callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
var ngb_rates =  'http://lari.jumpstart.ge/en/api/v1/nbg_rates?callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
$http.jsonp(ngb_currencies).success(function(currency) {
    $scope.results =   currency.results;
})
.error(function(data) {
    alert("ERROR");
 });

$http.jsonp(ngb_rates).success(function(data) {
    $scope.result =   data.result;
})
.error(function(data) {
    alert("ERROR");
}); 
})
```

(first one is api call to get currencies, second is to get rates for a certain currency)
How do I make changes in the ngb_rates url so I get somegting like http://lari.jumpstart.ge/en/api/v1/nbg_rates?currency=USD,GBP so I load the rates for the other currencies?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure, if this helps you:

```
var ngb_currencies = 'http://lari.jumpstart.ge/en/api/v1/nbg_currencies?callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
var ngb_rates =  'http://lari.jumpstart.ge/en/api/v1/nbg_rates?callback=JSON_CALLBACK?currency=cur';
var cur = []; //Assume passing value GBP,USD in an array. 

$http.jsonp(ngb_currencies).success(function(currency) {
    cur = currency.results;
    getCurrency();
})
.error(function(data) {
    alert("ERROR");
});

function getCurrency() {
    $http.jsonp(ngb_rates).success(function(data) {
        $scope.result =   data.result;
    })
    .error(function(data) {
        alert("ERROR");
    });
}
```

Cheers